My phx and scr file changes aren't doing anything in game. (Dead Island)
I am in the process of modifying Dead Island's game files. Started out just changing a xml file with run speed, durability, attack speed, etc. However, once I started trying to edit phx and scr files nothing seems to be working.
Starting with the problem I ran into. I noticed that once I started messing around with the sprint speed mechanics I would take damage and die if I put the value too high. The limit turned out to be 15 which will coincide later half of post.
regular movement and sprinting use these properties [from default_level.xml in data0.pak]:
<prop n="MoveForwardMinSpeed" v="2.5"/>

<prop n="MoveForwardMaxSpeed" v="5.5"/>

<prop n="MoveBackwardMinSpeed" v="2.5"/>

<prop n="MoveBackwardMaxSpeed" v="4.5"/>

<prop n="MoveStrafeMinSpeed" v="2.5"/>

<prop n="MoveStrafeMaxSpeed" v="4"/>

<prop n="MoveSprintSpeed" v="13.5"/>

<prop n="MoveSprintStaminaConsumption" v="0.05"/>

<prop n="MoveAcceleration" v="50"/>

<prop n="MoveDeceleration" v="60"/>

Yesterday, I ended up finding one .phx and 2 .scr files in the physics folder of data0.pak that were the cause of this.
Namely:

odephysicswalkfly.phx

ai.scr

ramai.scr


[these are names of the files with their respective extensions, not an actual link so do NOT click on it if stack overflow creates link automatically.]
The parameters causing conflict:
PhysicsParams()
{
CollisionDamageToMeMul(1, 1)
CollisionDamageToMeSpeedThreshold(15, 15)
}
[notice the threshold is same as the sprint speed value where I started taking damage while running.]
Only problem is, I have tried changing these collision parameters in multiple ways yet nothing has worked yet.
Changed damagetomemul to (0, 0)
Changed Threshold to (30, 30) or even (50, 50)
I have tried changing all 3 in sync. Then, only the phx. Finally, only the scr files yet nothing worked. I am still taking damage and dying if my speed is 15+. Honestly, I am very new to this (started 2 days ago), but it seems like I can't just simply edit the phx and scr files the same way as I did the xml.
I even tried changing all 3 in both the pak and unzipped version in the game directory.
If anybody has experience working with these types of files or dead island specifically the help would be much appreciated.
Thank you
supplementary info:
CollisionDamageToMeMul() is set to (1, 1) for phx and (0,0) for the scr files.
CollisionDamageToMeSpeedThreshold() is same for all 3.
There is an unzipped data folder that is a copy of the data0.pak
path for 3 files:
phx:
DIDE\DI\Data0.pak\data\odephysics\generic\odephysicswalkfly.phx
scr:
DIDE\DI\Data0.pak\data\odephysics\walkfly\ai.scr
DIDE\DI\Data0.pak\data\odephysics\walkfly\ramai.scr
All that I have tried is mentioned above.
